# How to find when an android device enters deep sleep and leaves it?

Tags: android, power-management

Is there any means to find the time and durations at which an android device stays in deep sleep ?

Deep sleep for an android phone is the time at which the processor goes idle. <strike>I have seen many applications like CPUSpy showing that the device have been in deep sleep for so and so hours, I am not sure how those apps measure that out.</strike>

> CPUSpy reads Deep sleep hours by reading the following file :
>   /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state

The aim that I am trying to achieve is to generate a log that would help me understand when a device enters deep sleep and when does it leave deep sleep (eventhough the device might be in sleep).

So far what I have planned with my limited experience is that I am going to write a service that will insert a row into sqlite db during short fixed intervals of time when the screen is off with the screen state and will stop only when a row of screen on is inserted. So that when device goes into deep sleep the table will have a different interval between the rows without a screen on row in between.

I know the idea seems silly and will increase power consumption but is there a better way to find deep sleep hours ?

Comment: Why not just compare a clock that runs when the processor is asleep to one that doesn't, and detect periods of sleep by change in the difference?  You'd still have the challenge of keeping your monitoring process active so that it can run whenever the processor is awake, but it would have to do a lot less.

Comment: Yeah, no more database to worry about. That's a huge improvement thanks @ChrisStratton